# YouTube: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I am using a couple of different tools:  [Powershell-YouTube-Upload](https://github.com/JoJoBond/Powershell-YouTube-Upload)
&
[YouTube Kodi Addon](https://koditips.com/setup-use-youtube-kodi-addon) that require a valid Google Cloud API `client ID` and `client secret`.  However, in both cases, they return the same error message:

> The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota

I think I'm doing something wrong when creating my Google Cloud project and respective OAuth 2.0 Client ID *(with respective clientID & client secret)*.

Could someone tell me the minimum steps necessary to create a Google Cloud API project and respective clientID/client secret that doesn't produce the "exceeded your quota" error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quota is the number of requests your application is allowed to make in a period of time.

- There are project based quotas, these quotas limit how much data your project as a whole can request.
- Then there are user based quotas this limits the amount of data each user of your project can make during a period of time normally per minute or per 100 seconds. This is probably to prevent flooding.

Remember that the YouTube api is cost based not request based so each request you make has a cost.  You can see the [Cost calculator here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

You will need to make fewer requests if you have reached the end of your quota or request additional quota.

[Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota for beginners 2021.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc&t=1s)

## Where to find your current quota

Go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) for your project under library. search for YouTube data api click on it and you should see this

[image]

Click the manage button

Then on the left click on quota

[image]

This is where you can see how much quota your application currently has.

If your current quota says 0 don't be alarmed this happens and you will just need to apply for a quota extension before you can use the API.

Click the link at the top of the page

[image]

Getting an extension can take anywhere from a week to three months. So be patent

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Below screenshot is what I see in my Quotas page.  Can you please tell me what I need to do specifically to fix this? [Quotas screenshot page](https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cDovL291Y3ZscS5zbi5maWxlcy4xZHJ2LmNvbS95NHBkUHd0TzJEYWg5ckk1dkI0M1U1a0JlWWhEczg3S3RiM2xQU0VGTmVNVG9QOUR6LXFzZHFXcGNaNzdPTUxQMjBMUDJkUW1NVWQtZGZLeUdNTlVNRVM0cFVYanJhNThDX09nU2JfcUpIUFhEbTFBWF9ONW5OaHlWZm9JcW9NREJoTmt5VHk4MExJNDh1ZFZxdmZmenNTTUkzbUZsVG8wRUtHVW1YZ3RqdFVqS2lwZVp4bmtyLUNhY3ppejdjeU5FMHZ1dnNadGhpSVgtRVBselppcDBzbTY1WFBDcmk1ZGNPRkItRGJnckZpUkdr/root/content)

Comment: It looks like I may need to fill out the form:  https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en  However, it looks like these questions were meant for the developers for **Powershell-YouTube-Upload** & **YouTube Kodi Addon** apps (links for these apps in my Stackoverflow question).  Id really appreciate it if you could please assist me with answering the app-specific questions since I didn't make these apps.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of app you have you still need to have quota to access the API. If you look at queries per day it shows you have 0 quota a something should pop out on the right when you click on it where you can fill out the form to apply for quota.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much! Can I see somewhere the current amount of quota used? I mean the current used cost of the quota I have already used from my limit.

Comment: Theres nothing that i know of that shows current quota.  You can see the requests that have been made over in the manage page.  But thats not known for being Realtime or accurate.